# Docker compose remote absolute volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 machines

- `machine A` (windows + docker cli + docker compose)
- `machine B` (ubuntu + docker daemon)

At `machine A` I have a `docker-compose.yaml` who maps a volume to `/var/shared:/data`. The folder `/var/shared` is in `machine B` (docker daemon), a samba share that I upload my database files for my docker services.

This is `my docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  db:
    image: 'jacobalberty/firebird:2.5-ss'
    volumes:
      - /var/shared:/db
    environment:
      ISC_PASSWORD: 'masterkey'
  app:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "4003:4003"
```

I want to `up` the compose but I getting this:

```
> docker-compose up
....
Cannot create container for service db: create \var\shared: "\\var\\shared" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path
```

Answer (score 0):

volumes:
      - /var/shared:/db

/var/shared--this is the volume name.
only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed.

you can change /var/shared to var_shared.